Python command works in term but doesn't in eshell
I'm trying to run a python script using selenium (that should call the executable geckodriver, installed) but, while the script runs in term, it errors in eshell (and in the python console).
A minimal sample giving the error is
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Firefox()

that gives the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 67, in _binary_paths
    output = SeleniumManager().binary_paths(self._to_args())
  File "/home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 47, in binary_paths
    args = [str(self._get_binary())] + args
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 99, in _get_binary
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unable to obtain working Selenium Manager binary; {path}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain working Selenium Manager binary; /home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    webdriver.Firefox()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/home/piripuz/.conda/envs/scommesse/lib/python3.13/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 78, in _binary_paths
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for firefox; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

on the other hand, the same code works perfectly when launching it from a terminal. Note that, from the working and non-working consoles, the commands
os.environ["PATH"]

and
sys.executable

yield the exact same output.
As you can see, I'm using conda in a linux machine.
Does anyone understand what is going on and how could I have the code running in emacs?

Please post a question - it's not clear what the question is, here.

Thanks! I edited it, I hope it is better now

Use a python debugger to step through the code and find out how it is broken, or find the Selenium community and ask them. This probably isn’t anything to do with Emacs, but is probably just a missing environment variable.

Unrelated but potentially useful comment: Selenium's webdriver.SomeBrowser() is badly designed. You'd expect it to search your $PATH and fail if nothing found, but what it does instead is it may randomly download browser driver (even if you already have one in $PATH), and then fail because this random driver mismatches your system browser version. So as a rule of thumb, you'd usually want to call webdriver.SomeBrowser(service = Service(my_driver_path)), where my_driver_path is calculated by you by searching for binary on the system.

…with that said, I just tested calling webdriver.Chrome(service = Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver')) from both term and eshell, and it works in both cases. OTOH, if I omit the path, it fails equally in both term and eshell. So… well, it may be useful to figure out why autodetection doesn't work in eshell for you, but I'd just point out that Selenium autodetection is simply not something you should rely upon, so I'm not sure it's even worth spending your time trying to solve this.
